# How to setup android L environment in eclipse IDE

Tags: android, installation, material-design

Can any one tell me that how to set android L environment in eclipse.I updated my sdk tools to 24.1.2. And i downloaded sample code from [here](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) and then i got errors called **The import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView cannot be resolved** can any one tell me how to setup android L environment in eclipse

Comment: take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29252642/4290431 @RD

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click in your project -> Properties
2. In the tab libraries, click in "Add External Jars"
3. Select "android support v7" and "RecyclerView" jars.

Paths:
`path-to-android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`,

`android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/recyclerview/libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar`

4. Go to tab "Order and Export", check the two jars, click in ok
5. Add this import to your activity: `import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;`
6. Try to build your project again!