# Unable to use appcompat-v7 in eclipse for material design

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have imported appcompat-v7 following this instruction to both Eclipse(Luna) and Android Developer Tools. 
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Now my appcompat-v7 library looks something like this in project explorer.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcs8L.jpg]

---

After importing this I have created a new project and added appcompat-v7 library with it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RACcG.jpg]

---

But after clicking ok if I again go to that option it looks different.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh2Gy.jpg]

---

If I put the following code to styles.xml it shows error.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
```

Now, what should I do to develop material design app using eclipse. Can anyone give me complete guideline to develop material app using eclipse?

NB: I have installed support library and I have api 21, 22 both.

Comment: Check my answer here. It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29252642/4290431 @Big Guy

Comment: after including lib just restart eclipse.

Comment: In step 2 you mentioned that add this lib to build path of your project. Can you please explain that for me? And also mentioned if create project targeting version 21 (Android L Preview) there should be only 2 values folder in res folder. But, I have 4. Values, values-v11, values-v14,values-w820dp.

Whats wrong with me! @Pooja

Comment: Right click on Project. Go to option "Build path". In that select "Configure build path". One window will be open. In that window, under library tab, add `appcompat-v7. Check it and ok it. @BigGuy

Comment: Oh. ok. I already did this when I imported appcompat-v7. What about the values folders?

Answer (score 1):

Just now I faced the same issue. I solved it using below steps. Hope it helps you.

Remove `appcompat-v7` lib from your project property which is showing error.

Now right click on the `appcompat-v7` lib. Go to Property. Make sure "is library" option is checked.

Clean all projects.
Now right click on your project. Go to property and add `appcompat-v7` again. In my project `appcompat-v7` build target was 21 so I change project build target to 21.

Clean all projects and restart eclipse.

Comment: Removed appcompat-v7 from my project properties.
In appcompat-v7 "is library" is checked.
Cleaned project and targeted 21.
But still doesn't work.

Comment: Then I think it is some else issue.  @BigGuy

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution is make shore both library and project is in same workspace means check on copy project in workspace during import library.
Hope this solve your problem because it solve mine.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and solved it by  placing app compact v7 library folder and project in same directory. go to property and check that your library and appcompact is in same directory.
You can follow this tutorial for solving this problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG_HxvV44zM

Comment: That tutorial helped me. Thanks