# Style showing error in android

Tags: android, android-styles

The following style shows error in eclipse

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

it shows a error like this

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
```

while i searched, i get to know that it is the problem of the dependency. I tried a lot to solve it. But i still get the same error .

If i change the theme there is no error, but i need this particular style.

I tried the following theme

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">     
     // Your style here
```

this is woking . but i need the above theme .

Comment: try adding AppCompat library

Comment: already tried . that's doesn't work for me

Comment: Drop android:style/ and put parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: well it works for me that ways . I have added 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' in my dependencies and don't have android:style/appended before. Try rebuilding your project

Comment: unfortunately not for me. i am stuck at this for past two days .

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: what class are you extending from on activities? full logcat?

Comment: @rogerthatcode:  ActionBarActivity

Comment: @random : i did't get you

Comment: Try extending from AppCompatActivity

Comment: How do you add your dependency? Through eclipse or android studio? If through android studio, wanted to see your build.gradle

Comment: You have not added `AppCompat v7` lib properly in your project. @VV

Answer (score 0):

If your activity extends `AppCompactActivity`, your parent theme should be

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

where as, if using `ActionBarActivity`, theme should be

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Make sure you have [set up the dependencies](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) in your project. This feature required `appcompactv7`.

Comment: i am using the 2nd one

Comment: i have added a link in ans. please check.

Comment: i updated the support lib. After that should i create a new dependency?

Comment: no, its different in eclipse.  Just go through the page and you will understand.