# Configure Eclipse for Material Design

Tags: android, eclipse, material-design

How do I configure My App to use Material Theme. I don't wanna use Android Studio because its too slow and freezes a lot. I have read the instructions from answer [to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240839/android-material-design-in-eclipse).
I followed the steps but I didn't get values-21 folder as mentioned in the answer. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference at project folders structure in this case in Eclipse and AS, maybe you just can't get right preview at Eclipse.

Comment: May be. But whenever I used android:style/Theme.Material... it gave me errors. When I tried @Colin method , it didn't produce error but the app crashed.

Comment: Check out your imported libraries at gradle Android Studio and just make the same at Eclipse but manually.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you currently have a folder `res/values` that has a file `styles.xml` which contains your apps theme. Manually create a folder `res/values-v21` and copy your `styles.xml` into it. Modify the new file now so that it uses the material theme as its parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now when your app is run on a device/emulator running API 21+ it will use the Material theme.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but Now my app crashed.